# How to remove/postDelayed runnables in Java?

Tags: java, runnable

Upon an event, I'd like to run a task/runnable but delay it's execution in 2 seconds.

During these 2 seconds, if the same event occurs, I'd like to remove the previous task and re-post it to run - again delayed by 2 seconds.

An example scenario would be background compilation. When a file is saved, I'm waiting 2 seconds and start compiling the class and other, depending classes. I don't want to do it all the time - especially if there are editors that save files automatically, like IntelliJ IDEA.

So, **how can I remove/postDelayed runnables in Java**, like Android's Handler ([remove](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)) / [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool` in order to schedule the task,
and you can follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679579/removing-all-queued-tasks-of-an-threadpoolexecutor)'s answer :

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = threadPool.getQueue();
```

in order to get the queued runnables.

Comment: Eventually, I used a variant of this solution, using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. I schedule a task to be delayed, but the remove didn't work, because it doesn't compare correctly tasks. What I do instead is clear the queue altogether. A bit nasty but works.

Comment: Wouldn't Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor give you behavior more like Android's Handler?  This would guarantee that Runnables posted to it would execute sequentially instead of in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

To delay any task and "restart" the delay, you can use [Swing timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) and if it is running, use its method `restart`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use the [`ScheduledExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html/Executor.html) to accomplish this, by adding a mechanism to replace queued tasks with re-queued ones. You could look into the source code of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to give an idea, perhaps overriding the implementation of `ScheduledFuture<?> schedule( Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit unit )` and figuring out to avoid the scheduling, only running the tasks once.

Cheers,